# parsing a html report file

Tags: java, html, xml

I am trying to extract the text content of a html file generated bu some tool.
I cant use normal sax or dom parser because html is not properly formed.

So i tried using htmlparser http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Now how can i extract the node i required?

I used this following code but it doesnot read node text content.It just  prints tds with its attibute.How can i fetch nodes body?

```
td colspan="2"
td valign="top" class="titleText"
```

I want to extract whose body has a number and a % symbol

```
String inputHTML = readFileAsString(filePath);
Parser parser = new Parser();
parser.setInputHTML(inputHTML);
parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");    
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null);
NodeList tds = nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("td"),true);

for(int i= 0; i < tds.size(); i++) {
    Node node = tds.elementAt(i);
    System.out.println(node.getText());
}
```

Comment: dom parser can easily extract

Comment: it gives exception as html is not well formeed.Some closing tags are missing

Comment: thats not a problem ,,dom can parse if tags are not closed also,,if not welformed also no problem to fetch the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's HTML, an HTML parsing library like Jsoup can deal with HTML and all of it's likely nastiness.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the JavaDocs for that library, you'll see that getText() is supposed to return exactly what you are seeing: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#getText()

I'd try calling getChildren(); it looks like one of the children will be a TextNode, which should contain the text you're looking for. See http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Node.html#getChildren() and http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html

Totally untested guess at how this would work:

```
for(int i= 0; i < tds.size(); i++) {
    Node node = tds.elementAt(i);
    System.out.println(node.getChildren().elementAt(0).getText());
}
```

You'll of course want to make sure getChildren().elementAt(0) exists first...

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you get an error? If not, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Html cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to clean your code
2. Construct DOM parser
3. Use XPath to extract the data you want

Sample code to clean your html.

```
private Document clean(String content) throws ParserConfigurationException {
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    TagNode rootNode = cleaner.clean(content);

    // convert to DOM
    CleanerProperties properties = new CleanerProperties();
    properties.setOmitComments(true);
    DomSerializer domSerializer = new DomSerializer(properties);
    Document doc = domSerializer.createDOM(rootNode);
    return doc;
}
```

Now you have the DOM document so you dont need to build DOM parser.

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

XPath doc can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).
e.g

```
NodeList columns = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//view[@name=\"" + viewName + "\"]/column", root, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

gets all the `view` nodes, present anywhere in root node, whose has and attribute called `name` with value `viewName`

Not passing anything as last attribute or passing `XPathConstants.STRING` gives the content of the matching node.